# inserting an element to a binary search tree and find its level

Tags: java, binary-tree

I have written such the code below that ;

I have an array list which has `3` objects . each object has `2 fields 1)digit2)level`

I want to insert each object to a binary search tree and after inserting each element to the tree ,I need to find its level.

Code:

```
private void greedyMethod(ArrayList<Element> array) {
    //it will print the objects in the array list.
    System.out.println(array.toString());

    array.get(0).setLevel(1);
    root = new DNode(array.get(0), null, null);
    for (int i = 1; i < array.size(); i++) {
        insert(array.get(i));
    }
}

private void insert(Element e) {
    root = makeBST(root, e);
}

private DNode makeBST(DNode root, Element e) {
    if (root == null) {
        root = new DNode(e, null, null);
        // This will print wrong objects.
        System.out.println(root.getElement().toString());
    } else if (e.getDigit() < root.getElement().getDigit()) {
        e.setDigit(root.getElement().getLevel() + 1);
        root.prev = makeBST(root.prev, e);
    } else if (e.getDigit() > root.getElement().getDigit()) {
        e.setLevel(root.getElement().getLevel() + 1);
        root.next = makeBST(root.next, e);
    }

    System.out.println(averageAccessTime);
    return root;
}
```

my array list is :

```
[digit :25   level:0, digit :27   level:0, digit :26   level:0]
```

but as I mentioned in the code above,the line :
    `System.out.println(root.getElement().toString());` prints wrong objects (I mean wrong digit or wrong level!!!!)-->

```
digit :27  probability: 0.2 level:2
digit :3  probability: 0.1 level:2
```

please help me to find my mistake ,thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
e.setDigit(root.getElement().getLevel() + 1);
```